# IPhone adding UiComponents to UiScrollView on run time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uiview

I'm new to objective C, I have a view based application which communicates with a web service and recives an xml, parse it and map its contens an appropriate view component (e.g if thats a date show the question with datepicker, if question has 2 values show it with a segmented control, if more with a pickerview..etc) so its a dynamic questionary with many pages filled with multiple components.

how can I do the design for the mapping the xml response into related UI view components on runtime? I want to make the code as object orient as possible and not too many if elses in my view controller class, but instead it should only receive a let's say "uiview object" filled with necessary view components and it will just show it. I have a UiScrollView and want to add new different approprite Uicomponents(Picker, textbox, label..) to it on real time, How can I do this? I think in the Interface builder I only need to put the scrollview and the rest will be in code? and using a scrollview a good choice here? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.view addSubView: imageview];
[self.scrollView addsubview:pickerview];
[self.view addSubView:scrollview];
```

like wise the custom view may be like uibutton,textfield,textview,imageview

Comment: tnx, what is customobjectview and what is customobject? lets  say i wanna add one picker view and one textbox to a scroll view, can you tell me how do i that and also where should i put the delegate methods of picker view? since they will be runtime created dont know how and where to add delegates..

Comment: custom object means your picker view .for example [self.scrolview addsubview:pickerview];

Comment: do you recommend to subclass uikit as another approach ?

Answer (score 1):

you can't do without a UIScrollView. you have to define the set of elements you wan to inject into your view and make case statement for the xml data you are receiving in your receiving data handler.

If you are new to Objective-C (i.e. CocoaTouch) and if your polls are fixed enough , maybe you could try setting up the differents views in the code and the data you are retrieving from the net will be to decide which view to display.

another tip will be to subclass UIKit elements to init them from a XML node.

Comment: which one is easy to do? I am a java programmer but very less experience in Obj-C. One scroll page can include multiple components, so how can I set different views in advance since they are not static and dont know the next page's components? and I dont know where and how to implemenet the delegete methods of this components? tnx

Comment: each time you change the subviews of your scroll view, call the setContentSize method of the scroll view to alert it of resizing needs.

Comment: also, you can have a look at: WWDC 2010: Session 104 - Designing Apps with Scroll Views

WWDC 2011 : Session 104 - Advanced Scroll View Techniques Session 115 - Scrolling, Swiping, Dragging

Comment: tnx could you also check my last question?

Comment: you can use ivars for setting ui components in advance, and change them in your connection delegate methods. your delegate methods are to be set in the class used for handling the response. you should post some code if you want more specific help. what books/tutos do you use for learning CocoaTouch ?

Comment: Thanks! I will use navigation controller, and uitable view, parse xml and fill the uitablecells with necessary components using ivars(am I correct?) I have a lot of books but you can reccommend more if thats related

Comment: that's a way, but I'm not sure UITableView is the best to present UI Control elements. You can stick with the scrollView (UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView). I don't have intro books to recommend but  I like “iOS 4 Programming Cookbook”.

Comment: please also check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620425/iphone-can-i-use-uitableview-for-this-purpose