# Iphone can I use uitableview for this purpose

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I plan to use a UINavigation controller with UITableView for a multi page questionary application here below how my questions looks like:

My question is can I really use uitableview/tableviewcell for this purpose? I heard that it makes good memory management with long lists and easy to code but I also heard I may not able to put controllers like datepicker in it? I dont want to use scrollview because then it will be hard to manage questions as component groups and manage memory.

Also Considerding that I already Use UITableview what is the best and easy practise here to show radiobuttons and checkboxes, getting the user input from the user should also be easy and not complicated delegate patterns.

- picker views and putting them into a alertshield
- show them as a list with custom radiobutton and checkbox icons
- using pickerview in another way

> Page1--------------------
>
> Label: enter your Name
>
> Texbox
>
> Hidden label: you must enter your
>   name
>
> Hidden Label:[empty]
>
> ---
>
> Label: enter your date if birth
>
> Uidate picker
>
> Hidden label: you should be above 18
>
> Hidden Label:[empty]
>
> ---
>
> Label: Choose all kind of credits you
>   want?
>
> UIpicker view with credit types
>
> Hidden label: choose at least 2 credit types
>
> Hidden Label: this is explanation
>   text of credits.
>
> .    .
>   *any many questions like this*    .
>
> --End of Page1-----------

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short. Yes you can. The problem with UITableView and UIPicker is that both use gesture recognizers for swiping. And if you will add an UIPicker to a cell and your table would be able to scroll then you would have a problem. You could present your UIPicker in the UIAlertSheet instead of directly in the cell.

Comment: thanks there will be 10-15 questions in each page, alertshiled..that sounds interesting! If I use UIAlertSheet then it will be pop up when user clicks on that cell? then how will user know that something will pop up when he clicks there?

Comment: @XDeveloper, it all depends on your UI, you could add and arrow indicator and a word "pick" to the table cell or you could make that cell look different.

Comment: actually I need radiobuttons, checkboxes. I thought I could use pickerviews for this purposes. considering that I will use uitableview let me know if there is better ideas rather than using pickers